# Deleting an item in an array by moving the next into its place

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I'm having problems with this method. This method is in a file called `vectorOfDogs` and as it says, it's suppose to delete the specific dog by the tag number passed into it and push everything up one. after the push, it's suppose to decrease size. This method gives me an `arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the commented line below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Dog[] theDogs = new theDogs[capacity]
```

```
public void deleteDog(int tgNm) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (theDogs[i].getTagNumber() == tgNm) {
            for (int j=i; j<size; j++) {
                theDogs[j] = theDogs[i+1]; //this line gives an exception
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the dog has been deleted");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of "size" here. debug that one. As it's throws "arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" then i am sure size > capacity.

Comment: Why don't you just make it an `ArrayList` of type Dog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

- You shouldn't be modifying `i` inside the nested loop
- You should stop once you reach `size-1`, because you take element at `index+1`
- You should set the last item to `null`

Here is how you can fix this:

```
if (theDogs[i].getTagNumber() == tgNm) {
    for (int j=i; j<size-1; j++) {
        theDogs[j] = theDogs[j+1];
    }
    theDogs[--size] = null;
    i--;
}
```

Setting the last item to `null` prevent infinite looping in case when you delete the last dog.

Comment: thanks a lot this works but my problem (that i forgot to add) was how will i delete the last line in the list? can i just point it to null?  @desblinkenlight

Comment: but would it throw a null pointer exception when i'm trying to write the list into dogs.txt? @desblinkenlight

Comment: @afrojuju_ Since you are using an array, not a list, you keep track of the length of its "active part" (i.e. the `size` variable in your example). Deleting a dog from the list should decrease `size` by `1`. The tail portion of the array will be set to `null`s.

Comment: @afrojuju_ If there are no `null`s in the "active part" (i.e. in positions zero to `size`) you should have no null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating over the range of [0;size] storing the value in variable i and than you are incrementing i on the line you have marked, so if i=size-1 in the last iteration you try to access theDogs[size].

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public void deleteDog(int tgNm) {
   for (int i=0,int reduction=0; i<size-reduction; i++) {
      if (theDogs[i].getTagNumber() == tgNm) {
        reduction++;
        for (int j=i; j<size-reduction; j++) {
          theDogs[j] = theDogs[j+1]; //this line gives an exception
        }
      i--
    }
}
System.out.println("the dog has been deleted");
}
```